# Why Define the Box Topology in Terms of a Redundant Basis?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{X_i\}$ be an arbitrary collection of topological spaces.

Let $X = \prod X_i$.

I have seen in Munkres' textbook on Topology, for example, that we can define the box topology $\tau$ on $X$ via the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{\prod U_i : U_i$ is open in $X_i\}$.

But why define $\tau$ in terms of what $\mathcal{B}$ generates if they are the same sets (am I mistaken that they are indeed the same sets)?  Then my question specifically is if, under this definition, $\tau = \mathcal{B}$, why discuss a basis at all?

Comment: You seem to be confused: the set $\mathcal B$ in your question is not a basis for the product topology as soon as there are infinitely many factors; in fact, its elements are no even open in general!

Comment: Sorry -- I meant "box topology" in the text (it's been corrected now).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are mistaken; for example, consider the box topology on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ (which is actually just the same as the normal topology). Let $U=(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$, which is an open set. Then
$$(U\times\mathbb{R})\cup (\mathbb{R}\times U)$$
is a "thick plus sign" in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which cannot be expressed as $V\times W$ for any open $V,W\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Amazing how something so simple escaped my attention for several weeks.  This has clarified a lot of other proofs I've read involving Cartesian products.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: In case it helps anyone else with similar thoughts to my own -- the reason why this escaped my attention is that I've been intentionally not visualizing Cartesian products in the plane (instead viewing them as sets of ordered pairs across lines parallel to each other).  But in two-dimensions this makes it hard for certain sets to be visualized.  For example, the set you gave above falsely looks at first glance like $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ from this birds eye view since each point on the two lines (each representing $\mathbb{R}$) is covered.  If this doesn't make sense then ignore :)

Answer (score 4):

In general $\tau\supsetneqq\mathscr{B}$. For a simple example, consider $X=\square^\omega\Bbb R$, the box product of countably infinitely many copies of $\Bbb R$. Let $z$ be the point whose coordinates are all $0$. Then $X\setminus\{z\}$ is an open set not in $\mathscr{B}$.

For that matter, let $X$ be any Hausdorff space with at least two points. Let $\Delta=\{\langle x,x\rangle:x\in X\}$, the diagonal in $X\times X$ (which has the same topology both as a Tikhonov and as a box product). Then $X\setminus\Delta$ is an open set not in $\mathscr{B}$. To see this, let $x,y\in X$ with $x\ne y$; clearly $\langle x,y\rangle,\langle y,x\rangle\notin\Delta$. However, if $\langle x,y\rangle,\langle y,x\rangle\in U\times V$, then $x,y\in U\cap V$, and therefore $\langle x,x\rangle,\langle y,y\rangle\in(U\times V)\cap\Delta$.

Comment: Why are you using $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to denote ordered pairs?

Comment: @Peter: Because it’s a standard (albeit less common) convention that I prefer; parentheses are already overloaded. I suspect that most of the people who use it have some set-theoretic background.

Comment: What is meant by the $\square$ symbol?

Comment: @user1770201: I defined it in the answer: it’s the box product. When the factors are all the same, as they are here, so that it’s actually a box power, the number of factors is sometimes superscripted on the box, as I did it, rather than on the space.